# Update postgresql table column with increasing reference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table that have a reference column (different than the id).

I want to iterate on the table and add a reference code ('ITEM001', 'ITEM002", etc) for each line.

If I want to change for all line with the same reference, I do:

```
UPDATE stock SET reference = 'ITEM001';
```

How could I update the column of all table based on the id  ?

Current situation:

```
id    name            reference
1     item-name-1    
2     item-name-2   
3     item-name-3   
10    item-name-10   
11    item-name-11
```

Desired result:

```
id    name            reference
1     item-name-1     IT001
2     item-name-2     IT002
3     item-name-3     IT003
10    item-name-10    IT010
11    item-name-11    IT011
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Basing this on the `id` would be the simplest approach.

Comment: The real question is: why do you want to do that? The information is already available in the database and there is no need to store redundant data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char()` to format the number:

```
UPDATE stock 
   SET reference = 'IT' || to_char(id, 'FM000');
```

The `FM` parameter for the format mask makes sure that the formatted value does not contain any blanks.

But in general it is a bad idea to store information that can easily be derived from existing data.

The better solution would be to create a *view* that returns that information:

```
create or replace view stock_with_reference
as
select *, 'IT' || to_char(id, 'FM000') as reference
from stock;
```